# Is every subspace of a Banach space a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

In a book I'm reading (*Functional Analysis for Probability and Stochastic Processes* by *Adam Bobrowski*) Exercise 2.2.13 is as follows:

> Suppose that $\mathbb{Y}$ is a subspace of a Banach space $\mathbb{X}$. Show that $\mathbb{Y}$ is itself a Banach space, equipped with the norm inherited from $\mathbb{X}$.

Obviously every **closed** subspace of a Banach space is also a Banach space but if we do not required the subspace to be closed (which is the case in the exercise), then I think this claim is wrong.

Take for example the space $(L^{1}([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{1})$ with $\|f\|_{1}:=\int_{[0,1]}|f|d\lambda(x)$ which is known to be a Banach space. The space $(C([0,1]),\|\cdot\|_{1})$ is a subspace of $L^{1}([0,1])$. However $C([0,1])$ is the canonical example of a vector space which is not a Banach space.

Is there something I'm missing or is the exercise simply wrong?

Comment: It may be that the definition of subspace in your textbook includes the adjective "closed" to that in the exercise an assumption is missing (for example that the subspace is finite dimensional)

Comment: Yeah, or there is simply a typo and they meant to write close. You didn’t overlook anything either way.

Comment: @OliverDíaz made the right guess. Look at the definition (§2.2.6, two pages before your exercise) at the bottom of p.46 of your book. "$Y$ is called a subspace of $X$ if it is a closed algebraic subspace of $X$."

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah, yeah. I missed that definition. It seems the author distinguishes between *algebraic subspaces* and *closed algebraic subspaces* and defines the latter ones as subspaces.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what this quote says.

Comment: Is there a reason for this definition? While I first though this is exotic it seems there are other authors using the same distinction (f.e. *Kubrusly* in *Spectral Theory of Bounded Linear Operators*).

Comment: The reason is exactly this exercise! That you want 'subspaces' to be Banach spaces on their own right.

Comment: The close vote doesn't make any sense. The beginning of the OP states the context of the problem.